# Exporting Oracle Database Using TOAD

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have this strange error when exporting a database

this is the error report,

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.6.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

Export done in WE8MSWIN1252 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set

```
About to export specified users ...

. exporting pre-schema procedural objects and actions

. exporting foreign function library names for user WELTESADMIN 

. exporting PUBLIC type synonyms

. exporting private type synonyms

. exporting object type definitions for user WELTESADMIN 

About to export WELTESADMIN's objects ...

. exporting database links

. exporting sequence numbers

. exporting cluster definitions

. about to export WELTESADMIN's tables via Conventional Path ...

EXP-00008: ORACLE error 904 encountered
ORA-00904: "POLTYP": invalid identifier

EXP-00000: Export terminated unsuccessfully
```

I have granted the DBA access to the executor and this is what happened. Please help me...

Comment: thanks leo I will try it out. but whats wrong with my case ?

Comment: ORA-00904 indicates an invalid column name.  So, do you have a table with a column called POLTYP?  Or some variant (which would be more incriminting)?

Comment: @APC NO, i dont have column named poltype

Comment: So what *do* you have called POLTYP?  A table?  A user-defined type?  TOAD isn't picking "POLTYP" out of thin air.  It must be something in your data dictionary.  Consider that POLTYP might be a fragment of the actual identifier, if you've been doing something weird when naming objects.